# Azure Sendgrid : Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Unauthenticated senders not allowed

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-app-service-plans

So I'm using Sendgrid for an email form on a Azure website. When the form is submitted I get this error:

Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Unauthenticated senders not allowed

I know it looks like the username or password is incorrect because it is Unauthenticated senders not allowed, but I have other web sites using the same smtp settings on the same server, that work fine.

Also I tested the connection using this telnet and I get Authentication successful, with the same username and password provided.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: `What could be causing this error?` Have you added the key/value pairs under App settings? Have you refereced to [How to Send Email Using SendGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email#how-to-send-an-email) with Azure? Or would you mind sharing the demo code?

Comment: It was problem with my c# code. I was not authenticated while sending email using Smtp server. I had to set the credential right then it starts working.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed if u get your error then provide an answer and accept your answer also because it's convenient for other developers who come to know what's solutions this problem occurs